# Windowed Functions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table called `Orders` in which the data looks like this:

```
EMpID  OrderValue OrderID
1      100        1
2      167        89
....
```

There are multiple orders for each empID.
What I want is to get output in this form

```
EMPID RANK VALUETOTAL VALUETHISEMPID 
1     1    300        100
4     2    300        50\
.....
```

If there are multiple EmpID(s) With same ValueThisEmpID then it should get same rank.

I tried

```
SELECT EmpID,SUM(val) OVER() as VALUETOTAL,SUM(val) OVER(PARTITION BY EmpID)
```

How can I obtain rank and order it by ValueThisEmpID?

Comment: I have reached here SELECT DISTINCT EmpID, SUM(val) OVER() as VALUETOTAL, SUM(val) OVER(PARTITION BY EmpID) as VALUEEMP, 100 / SUM(val)OVER() * SUM(val) OVER(PARTITION BY EmpID) as PERCENTAGE FROM Sales.OrderValues ORDER BY VALUEEMP DESC The only thing now missing is Ranking

Comment: Your question did not mention percentages. Please update your question if you have additional criteria.

Comment: Actually i was thinking of adding percentage like what percentage of total sale, was done by a particular employee.

It's easy after ur help.

Thanks

Comment: Ok SInce i am not aware of the trick u used,I tried this and It worked


select 
 EmpId,  
    dense_rank() over(order by ValueThisEmpId desc) as "rank",  
    sum(ValueTHisEmpId) over() as ValueTotal,  
    ValueThisEmpId

from (SELECT EmpID,Sum(Val) as ValueThisEmpId FROM Sales.OrderValues Group By EmpID) A


Thanks a lot.

How can I change the background color of my code as done by someone for me in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some test data:

```
insert into #t values (1, 10, 100)
insert into #t values (1, 20, 101)
insert into #t values (2, 30, 120)
insert into #t values (3, 10, 130)
insert into #t values (3, 10.5, 131)
insert into #t values (4, 100, 140)
```

You need two steps, one to get empIds and their summed order value. Step two will be to get the total total and rank:

```
; with Step1 (EmpId, ValueThisEmpId) as
    (select empId, sum(OrderValue)
    from #t
    group by empId)
select EmpId, 
    rank() over(order by ValueThisEmpId desc) as "rank", 
    sum(ValueTHisEmpId) over() as ValueTotal, 
    ValueThisEmpId
from Step1
```

This will give output of:

```
4   1   180.50  100.00
1   2   180.50  30.00
2   2   180.50  30.00
3   4   180.50  20.50
```

If you don't want gaps in the ranking, use dense rank:

```
; with Step1 (EmpId, ValueThisEmpId) as
    (select empId, sum(OrderValue)
    from #t
    group by empId)
select EmpId, 
    dense_rank() over(order by ValueThisEmpId desc) as "rank", 
    sum(ValueTHisEmpId) over() as TotalValue, 
    ValueThisEmpId
from Step1
```